# Gdx-Pay check for purchases

Tags: ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I've finished setting up my IAP system but I can't figure out how to check if the user actually owns/have purchased a certain product.
Using Google IAP Billing for android I simply did:

```
Purchase ITEM_1 = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_1);
if(ITEM_1 != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(ITEM_1)){
//Give user the product
ITEM_1_BOUGHT = true;
}
```

I can't find an equivalent method for this in Gdx-Pay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PurchaseObserver` has a method called: `handleRestore(Transaction[] transactions)`

You can iterate through transactions:

```
@Override
public void handleRestore(Transaction[] transactions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
        // do something with all bought products.

        if (transactions[i].getIdentifier().equals("YOUR_PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER")) {
            // do something with a certain product
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for. But, this method is only called when PurchaseSystem.purchaseRestore(); if Im not mistaken?

Comment: Yes I think so. I think in the background it does: inventory.getPurchases();

Comment: Hm you see that brings problems. Since Apple commands you to have restore method on a button rather than during every startup, the user must manually restore the purchases(on that button) each time they enter the app in order to receive access to their purchases. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes, but I dont' see the problem. After first purchase or restore save what they user bought. Do not always use the restore method on each start. Load from your saved values.

Comment: @TomGrillGames Saving purchase-status in preferences seems insecure? Maybe that is not what you meant though? Since anyone could just edit that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a parent method getInformation() which is not showcased in any of the examples. You need to override it in the abstract PlatformResolver like

```
  public Information getInformation(String identifier){
    return mgr.getInformation(identifier);
  }
```

then in your game class you need check whether the purchase exists like:

```
   Information info = getPlatformResolver().getInformation(productId);
   String getName = info.getLocalName();
    if(getName == null)
        getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(productId);
```