# Gdx-Pay find previous purchases

Tags: libgdx, in-app-purchase

I'm using Gdx-Pay for cross-platforming my IAP's.
Everything is set up from Libgdx's wiki like:

```
if(PurchaseSystem.hasManager()){
        config = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
        config.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(item1));
        config.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(item2));
        config.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(item3));
        config.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(item4));

        //Stores
        config.addStoreParam(PurchaseManagerConfig.STORE_NAME_ANDROID_GOOGLE, base64EncodedKey);
        config.addStoreParam(PurchaseManagerConfig.STORE_NAME_IOS_APPLE, base64EncodedKey); // <-- CHANGE KEY

        PurchaseSystem.install(new PurchaseObserver() {
            @Override
            public void handleInstall() {
                message(" - purchase manager installed: " + PurchaseSystem.storeName() + ".\n");

                // restore purchases
                message(" - do a restore to check inventory\n");
                //PurchaseSystem.purchaseRestore();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleInstallError(Throwable e) {
                message(" - error installing purchase manager: " + e + "\n");

                // throw error
                throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleRestore(Transaction[] transactions) {
                // keep note of our purchases
                message(" - totally " + transactions.length + " purchased products\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
                    if(transactions[i].getIdentifier().equals(item1)) {
                        item1_purchased = true;
                    }
                    if(transactions[i].getIdentifier().equals(item2)) {
                        item2_purchased = true;
                    }
                    if(transactions[i].getIdentifier().equals(item3)) {
                        item3_purchased = true;
                    }
                    if(transactions[i].getIdentifier().equals(item4)) {
                        item4_purchased = true;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void handleRestoreError(Throwable e) {
                message(" - error during purchase manager restore: " + e + "\n");

                // throw error
                throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void handlePurchase(Transaction transaction) {
                message(" - purchased: " + transaction.getIdentifier() + "\n");

                // dispose the purchase system
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        message(" - disposing the purchase manager.\n");
                        PurchaseSystem.dispose();
                        message("Testing InApp System: COMPLETED\n");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void handlePurchaseError(Throwable e) {
                message(" - error purchasing: " + e + "\n");
                // throw error
                throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void handlePurchaseCanceled() {
                message(" - purchase cancelled.\n");

                // dispose the purchase system
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        message(" - user canceled! - disposing the purchase manager.\n");
                        PurchaseSystem.dispose();
                        message("Testing InApp System: COMPLETED\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        },config);

    } else {
        utils.toast_error("Connection failure, check your internet's connection");
    }
```

This is executed on my "create()" method in core class.

What I cannot work out is the relation between Android & IOS IAP.
Apple have a strict rule that purchase can only be "restored" on a button. 
But I find it extremely inconvenient to force the user into pressing a button every time they want to use a product in my app.

I have a table of products with buttons under each one saying either "Purchase"/"Use" , depending on if they have purchased the product or not.
So what I would find very pleasing is to have a method that simply "checks" if the user has ownership on each product when the app starts, and apply flags(booleans) as I iterate through the list.

I thought I could use "handleRestore()" for that as shown in my code. But apparently (I'm not sure), iterating through that list to check for purchases will make Apple decline my app since it will happen without the user's request.

So can I somehow just CHECK for purchases from the users Google/Apple account without executing a RESTORE request?

Comment: Same question here with solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32374839/1472483

Answer (score 1):

An alternate is to store the state of the purchases in a preference file and read from that when the app is launched. This will work both with android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you are supposed to keep track of what has been purchased yourself. e.g. when a user purchases something, write a file or a preference or some other persistent thing to keep track.

Apple spell it out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3

> After making the product available, your app needs to make a
>   persistent record of the purchase. Your app uses that persistent
>   record on launch to continue to make the product available. It also
>   uses that record to restore purchases, as described in Restoring
>   Purchased Products. Your app’s persistence strategy depends the type
>   of products you sell and the versions of iOS.

On Android you can do that as well, or on Android you can basically call 'Restore Purchases' on startup and let Android keep track of whats been bought.